# Function to read bmp file header

Tags: pointers, types, casting, header, bmp

```
unsigned char* Read_pixels(unsigned char *baseptr)
{
   unsigned char pixelinfo[4096]; 

   pFileheader->ID1 = *baseptr++;           // save B
   pFileheader->ID2 = *baseptr++;           // save M

   pFileheader->FileSize = *((unsigned int*)baseptr); 
   baseptr = baseptr + 4;

   pFileheader->Reserved = *((unsigned short*)baseptr);
   baseptr = baseptr + 2;

   pFileheader->Reserved2 = *((unsigned short*)baseptr);
   baseptr = baseptr + 2;

   pFileheader->PxOffset = *((unsigned int*)baseptr);

}
```

In this READ BMP function i receive a pointer to the start of a bmp file in a memory.
What i do in above code is read the fileheader and store the data in respective members of the fileheader structure.I have a doubt in the 5th line of code where i typecast a char pointer to an unsigned int.I do this because FileSize value is of unsigned int type and my baseptr is actually a char pointer.Have i done it right?Is the code corrrect?

Answer (score 0):

It is correct **if the endianness of your target machine is the same as the endianness within the BMP header**. In this case, it is correct for little endian machines, which is the case of x86 PCs.

If you are compiling for a target machine that use big endian, you unfortunately have no other choice than reading the four bytes making the word, and re-combining them to form the 32-bit integer you're willing to use.

A portable way to do it would be using the preprocessor, and having somewhere :

```
#ifdef BIG_ENDIAN
   length = ((length << 24) & 0xff000000)  /* Swap the 4 bytes within the word */
          | ((length <<  8) & 0x00ff0000)
          | ((length >>  8) & 0x0000ff00)
          | ((length >> 24) & 0x000000ff);
#endif
```

Also if I were you I'd dothat it using `memcpy` or `fread` in a structure that matches exactly the BMP header's fields, much more elegant than copingy every field individually :)

Finally a last tip, use types such as `uint32_t` instead of `unsigned int`, this assures you that you are using 32-bit `int`, as some machines use 16-bit ints and you need `long` to get a 32-bit integer.

Comment: i am going to use this on ARM ... so its a 32 bit int

Comment: Yes, and the endianness depends on the system. Most often ARM are wired up so they use the little endian order, but not always, so you should definitely check this !

Comment: ok.Basically i am going to read a bitmap image from pendrive and save it in my ARM controllers memory...then i will read it from memory when required...so how will the data be in memory...WILL the data "BM" look to me like "MB" ?OR  will 0x12345678 look to me like 0x78563412?

Comment: For 'B' and 'M' there is no possible error due to endianness since you read both bytes separatedly. As for the rest, ARM can be either endianness, so you should really check the documentation on the CPU/chip/board you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubts are justified. Casting this way assumes both your input file and the machine this runs on have the same endianness.

The safe thing to do is not assuming *anything* and not using the casts in the first place. There are standard functions to convert binary data to the 'platform' endianness (`ntohl`, `ntohs`, and `htonl`, `htons`), which do nothing if no conversion is needed, and convert otherwise. This works because their *library* implementations for the target OS know what endianness the system is running on.

Alternatively, consume larger values one byte at a time, and concatenate them in an endianness-unaware order. ("Unaware" for your program; the input endianness must be known!)

For example:

```
pFileheader->FileSize = (unsigned int)baseptr[0] +
     (((unsigned int)baseptr[1])<<8) +
     (((unsigned int)baseptr[2])<<16) +
     (((unsigned int)baseptr[3])<<24);
   baseptr = baseptr + 4;

pFileheader->Reserved =(unsigned int)baseptr[0] +
     (((unsigned int)baseptr[1])<<8);
   baseptr = baseptr + 2;
```

and so on. If used a lot, write a function or macro to read a word or 32-bit int.